# Formatting Text in Placeholders

Tags: officer

I'm using officer to create many ppt files.  I have a template that i have been using for over a year that's worked great.  Since the latest update (6.23.2019) the formatting of the placeholders in the slide master of the template do not persist to the output ppt.  For example, in the slide master, I have a placeholder that is size 18, red, Adobe Clean Light font.  When the ppt is rendered the text appears as size 24, black, Adobe Clean Bold font.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Seconding this. I noticed that all the placeholders on a single page have the same formatting and it seems to be the formatting of the placeholder at the topmost part of the slide.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a great answer as to why this is happening, but the crux of the issue is using type/id instead of ph_label.  If you use ph_label, the formatting persists from the template to the output ppt.

Comment: Each slide may have multiple types (e.g., 1 title, but maybe several body placeholders). But each placeholder can be identified by it's `ph_label`.